# How to use setTimeout() with slow function

Tags: javascript

in w3school (try it) I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img name="slide" class="slider" src="" width="400"/>

<script>
var i = 0;
var path = new Array();
path[0] = "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/batman/images/9/92/Batman-ArkhamKnight-BatsuitRender.png/revision/latest?cb=20140605151444";
path[1] = "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/injusticegodsamongus/images/c/c5/BATGIRL.png/revision/latest?cb=20130527034044";
path[2] = "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/injusticegodsamongus/images/b/bb/Raven_Render.png/revision/latest?cb=20130318184222";
path[3] = "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/injusticegodsamongus/images/7/7f/ARES.png/revision/latest?cb=20130411230035";

function swapImage() {
    document.slide.src = path[i];

    if (i < path.length - 1)
        i++;
    else 
        i = 0;

    setTimeout("swapImage()", 2000);
}

window.onload = swapImage;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I am trying to use `setTimeout` function and it works, but is it possible to change these images slow() ?

Comment: Do you understand this code?

Comment: Please find a better school - using a string in `setTimeout` is _so_ 1990's

Comment: Evan Knowles - I dont understand your comment, sorry. Please tell me whats wrong, what should I do. Whatever what can be helpfull, thanks.

Comment: p.s. you also need to explain when you mean by "slow"?   Do you mean you want it to animate somehow, rather than just swap?

Comment: yes I would like to add an animation

Comment: animation is relatively difficult - I'd highly recommend learning some jQuery (but learn as much pure JS as possible too!)

Comment: @Alnitak String in `setTimeout` does not even work for me! ...

Comment: Never pass the `callback` as a string. [MDN: setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout): `[...]the alternate syntax is a string [...] using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using eval()[...]`  instead just write it that way: `setTimeout( swapImage, 2000);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the duration of picture showing, you should change second argument of setTimeout from 2000 to wanted time (in milliseconds).

To use different effects on image swapping you should change line `document.slide.src = path[i];` to something else, depends on what kind of effect you are trying to invoke. Try using jQuery which has lot of nice effects out of the box, but you can use css to do that also. There are lot of ways well explained all around the internet so research a bit and find your own way.

Answer (score 0):

When you say change it "slow" does it mean to have fade in, fade out effect?
You can use jQuery to do that.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

In your example, change

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img name="slide" class="slider" src="" width="400"/>

...

function swapImage() {
    document.slide.src = path[i];

    if (i < path.length - 1) i++;
    else i = 0;

    setTimeout("swapImage()", 2000);
 }
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img name="slide1" class="slider" style="display:none;" src="" width="400"/>
<img name="slide2" class="slider" src="" width="400"/>

...


var current = document.slide1;
var next = document.slide2;

function swapImage() {
    var swap;
    current.src = path[i];
    next.src = path[i+1];

    if (i < path.length - 1) i++;
    else i = 0;

    jQuery(current).fadeOut();
    jQuery(next).fadeIn();

    swap = current;
    current = next;
    next = swap;

    setTimeout(swapImage, 2000);
 }
```

But in fact, using jQuery and other helper function will help you a lot.

Comment: Writing `In your example, change ... to ...` without any additional comment, indicates that this will create the fading. It is correct to suggest to change the code that way, but it is just an additional note and not a solution to the actual problem. Your answer is just a _link only answer_, so either leave it as comment or create a working example for the usage of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.